# Issues writing my first function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm new to programming and writing my first function for MATLAB. The name of the function should be "picalc". 
The purpose is to accept an "x" and "y" value as input arguments. These values must be plugged into x^2+y^2, and if this result is less than or equal to 1, return true. Otherwise, return false. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
function[true,false]=picalc(x,y);
if x^2+y^2<=1
    return true 
else
    return false
end
```

Can anyone tell me why this won't work? As it stands, I get the following error:

```
Error: File: picalc.m Line: 6 Column: 13
Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Thank you very much for your expertise!

Comment: That's not the syntax for returning values in MATLAB.  The correct syntax is `outputvar = value;`  No "return" involved.

Answer (score 4):

In MATLAB, `return` does not return value as an output of a function call but rather returns control to the invoking function (see documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html?searchHighlight=return)). As such, it does not take argument, because what it does is merely redirecting the flow of the program to the function/statement that invokes the function/statement containing the `return` statement.

Your function should be written like this:

```
function result = picalc(x,y);
if x^2+y^2<=1
    result = true; 
else
    result = false;
end
```

The variable on left hand side of the function declaration is the output variable. By assigning value to this valuable, you are "returning" an output.